# How to kill all child processes spawned by a process started from a script on kill or kill -9

Tags: linux, bash, kill-process

I have a shell script called Launcher.sh that gets executed by a java process. The java process internally uses ProcessBuilder to execute the bash script.

Inside the Launcher.sh, I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "kill -- -$$ && kill -INT -$PID" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL
bash Process_A.sh &
pid=$!
echo $pid
```

The Process_A script will spawn another child process called Process_B.

I want to kill both Process_A and Process_B when the Launcher.sh script receives a "kill" command or "kill -9" command from its parent the java process.

So I added a trap command to trap SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGKILL interrupts.
But when I do

```
kill $pid
```

it only kills Process_A but not the child Process_B. Both have the same PGID.

How can I kill all the child and grandchild processes spawned from my launcher.sh script correctly?

Here is an actual output of "ps j" before and after kill.
Inside my script I do "dse spark" which inturn spawns a java process. I want this java process to be killed when the launcer script gets a kill signal

```
root@WeveJobs01:~# ps j
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 2380  2381  2381  2281 pts/1    59265 S        0   0:00 /bin/bash
    1 58917 58916  1152 pts/0     1236 S        0   0:00 bash /usr/bin/dse spark
58917 59041 58916  1152 pts/0     1236 Sl       0   0:07 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre//bin/java -cp /etc/dse/spark/:/usr/share/dse/dse-
 2381 59265 59265  2281 pts/1    59265 R+       0   0:00 ps j

root@WeveJobs01:~# kill 58917

root@WeveJobs01:~# ps j
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 1152  1235  1235  1152 pts/0     1236 S        0   0:00 sudo -s
 1235  1236  1236  1152 pts/0     1236 S+       0   0:00 /bin/bash
    1 59041 58916  1152 pts/0     1236 Sl       0   0:23 /usr/bin/java -cp /etc/dse/spark/:/usr/share/dse/dse-
 2381 59513 59513  2281 pts/1    59513 R+       0   0:00 ps j
```

I tried this..and when I do "kill pid" where pid is that of the script. I get segmentation fault as it goes to infinite loop

```
trap 'echo "Kill All"; kill -TERM -$$' TERM INT
bash child.sh &
PID=$!
wait $PID
trap - TERM INT
wait $PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?
```

Comment: `SIGKILL` is not trappable (that's the point of kill). Otherwise how can you kill a malicious process that traps `SIGKILL` and ignores it? Kill the group instead.

Comment: Makes sense that I can't trap SIGKILL. I can still trap SIGTERM or SIGINIT right? How can I kill the process group on receiving SIGTERM?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: `kill [options] 0`, `kill [options] -- -$$`, `kill [options] $(jobs -p)`, etc.

Comment: So I tried this, and I'm getting a segmenation fault error as it's going into some infinite loop when I do "kill pid".

trap 'echo "Kill All"; kill -TERM -$$' TERM INT
bash child.sh &
PID=$!
wait $PID
trap - TERM INT
wait $PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?

Comment: You trap a SIGTERM then send another SIGTERM with `kill`? That's stupid (obvious infinite loop). It you want to kill, just `kill -9` (aka `kill -KILL`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to reset kill -term in the trap statement to prevent infinite loop. This worked

trap "trap -INT && kill -- -$$"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to kill a looping Bash script, depending on how the script is set up and how you want to stop it. Here are a few options:

Use the kill command to send a signal to the script process. For example, you can use kill -9  to send a SIGKILL signal to the script, which will immediately terminate it. Replace  with the process ID of the script. You can find the process ID by running ps aux | grep .

If the script is running in a separate terminal window, you can simply close the window to terminate the script.

If the script is running in the background, you can use the fg command to bring it back to the foreground, then press CTRL+C to terminate the script.

If the script is running in a loop that can be interrupted with a break statement, you can include a signal handler in the script that catches a signal and breaks out of the loop. For example:

```
trap 'break' INT
while true; do
  # script code goes here
done
```

This will cause the script to break out of the loop and terminate when it receives an INT signal (e.g., when you press CTRL+C).

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).